# Suggestions/sample code for fileSystemWatcher in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to build a fileSystemWatcher in java (similar to FileSystemWatcher in C#). Please suggest whether java has any built in framework capability for this or suggest/direct to any sample/open source projects.

Comment: You might want to give more information about the device the code needs to run on

Answer (score 7):

Check out the [Apache Commons JCI FAM](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jci/apidocs/org/apache/commons/jci/monitor/FilesystemAlterationMonitor.html) (FileAlterationMonitor). The [unit tests](https://github.com/apache/commons-jci/blob/master/fam/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/jci2/monitor/FilesystemAlterationMonitorTestCase.java) should give you an idea how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

"More NIO Features" in JDK7 should have a cross-platform version of such a facility (taking advantage of particular platform capabilities on any reasonable JRE implementation).

Answer (score 3):

it's more better choice
http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any inbuilt capability. You can always poll the directory in a thread, and watch for directory modification times etc. That's trivial, but I'm not sure how OSes differ in how they'll reflect directory changes in the directory meta data. If you have to keep track of a directory with a large number of files, any solutions based on polling may be quite heavyweight.

I note [this](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~qzhang/FileSystemWatcher.html), which is a more optimal version for Windows (not that I know what platform you're on!)

Comment: I need the solution to work on both windows and linux. It need not be super efficient as the directories(watched) will not be huge.

Comment: Then I'd poll for the modification time on the directory using File.lastModified()

Comment: Since Java 8 there is an inbuilt feature: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www2.hawaii.edu/~qzhang/FileSystemWatcher.html