# Ten latest files on disk

Tags: java, file-io

I need effective algorithm to keep only ten latest files on disk in particular folder to support some kind of publishing process. Only 10 files should present in this folder at any point of time. Please, give your advises what should be used here.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on the exact publishing process you're trying to implement?

Also, what's in the files? Why do you only need to keep 10?

Comment: There would be 10 content items. They need to be placed in folder on a disk. I could not open business idea. I think it does not mater.

Comment: Need more details on the requirements.  Are you writing a service that keeps track of folder?  Do you just need to remove older files once your program tries to publish something?

Comment: No services. Assume that i have file input stream and need to put it on disk and only ten of them(latest) should be kept on disk

Comment: So given those requirements you'll have to manually check the folder each time you write the file.  The File class has methods for reading directories and files in them which will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask the File for the directory to listFiles, if there are more than 9 sort them by lastModified() and delete the files oldest (smallest number) to trim down to 9.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a file system watcher like [JNotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/)?

1. Register for events that you are interested in (for instance, Created event);
2. Mark your internal list for the number of files upon every created event.
3. As soon as you reach the 11th file, remove the file having oldest create date.

Or use Commons JCI [FileAlterationMonitor](http://commons.apache.org/jci/commons-jci-fam/index.html) (FAM) to monitor local filesystems and get notified about changes:

```
ReloadingClassLoader classloader = new ReloadingClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
ReloadingListener listener = new ReloadingListener();

listener.addReloadNotificationListener(classloader);

FilesystemAlterationMonitor fam = new FilesystemAlterationMonitor();
fam.addListener(directory, listener);
fam.start();
```

This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730186/suggestions-sample-code-for-filesystemwatcher-in-java) may help you with file system watchers.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to poll the directory at regular intervals and delete everything that's older than the 10th oldest file in it.
Of course that leaves open to question what the "10th oldest file" actually is. The timestamp on the file might not indicate the date/time it was added to the folder after all.
So your system might actually need some independent way to keep track of files in the folder to determine when each was added, in order to delete files based on when they were 
put there rather than how old the file actually is.

But that's a business requirement you don't provide (do you even know it yourself?).